# How do I copy the emails from Google sheet people chip cells?

Tags: google-sheets

People chips are pretty cool, but copying from these cells only copies the full names of the people. How do I get the emails back?

Answer (score 6):

## Convert People Chip(s) to Email(s)

You can use the **Smart chips** menu to remove the **People Chip** which will convert it to an email address.  You can optionally do this to multiple **People Chips** at once.

1. Right-click on the selected **People Chip**(s)
2. Select **Smart chips** then **Remove smart chip**
3. The **People Chip**(s) will now be changed to email address(es).

## Copy Email from People Chip

You can copy the email address from the **People Chip**'s details.  You can only do this to one chip at a time.

1. Right-click on the **People Chip**
2. Select **Smart chips** then **Show details**
3. Copy the email address

---

## Smart Chips Menu

[image: Smart chips menu showing Show Details and Remove smart chip]

Answer (score 1):

[Extract data from smart chips in your Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13524011?hl=en) explains how to extract data from smart chips, including People, File, Event chip types. The help page explains using a graphical user interface `Data extraction` tool found under the `Data` menu.

Once email has been selected, the formula `=<cell reference>.email` is visible. So, for an example of people chips listed in column A, the formula `=A1.email` in column B will extract the email.